# control the text area when someone clicks on a link it opens

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have many text area in one page I get them by a link called "comment" so her is the idea I made a code in php that includes a form when the user clicks on "comment" this is an Ex.

> if(isset($_GET['comments']))                                                                                             {      $comments = $_GET['comments'];
>                   }
>                   if (!isset($_GET['comments'])) {
>                       $comments = "";
>                       } 
>                       if ($comments == "ok") {
>
> ```
>                       echo "<tr><td colspan='6' align='center'>";
>                       echo "<span class='rePost'>Re : &nbsp;</span><span
> ```
>
> class='blogerName'>$blog->ByName";
>   include "postComments.php";   echo
>   "";
>
> ```
>                      } ?>
> ```

now when the user clicks on comment it just includes the comment text area 
but here there is more then one threads on the same page or I can say more then one post on the same page so when the user clicks on "comment" on post one all the other posts get the text area below it.
what I need here is when the user clicks comment on post "1" the text area appear below post "1" and not 2 or 3 or any other one on this page.
I hope I got you to the point that I want.

I think it can be do by java or if anybody have a other idea please post it to me.

Comment: By Java, you certainly mean Javascript, which is absolutely different.

Comment: I think you mean JavaScript rather than java.

Comment: sorry for say Java and not Javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is best implemented by means of JavaScript as I think you meant when you said "Java". As the commenters have pointed out the two are not related.

Basically there is two ways you could approach this.

You could:

a) put out all of your TextAreas along with the page at all times but give them a css class with `display:none`. Each of the TextAreas or its surrounding container that you set to be invisible this way needs to have a unique id, too.

Then you can use a javascript function to assign another class that does not have the `display:none` property to any single id.

b) put out empty elements where the text areas are supposed to go later but also with a unique id. You'd then load HTML when it's needed by means of Javascript (AJAX). This is only a good choice if there are many possible elements and putting all of them out at all times blows up your page too much.

Does the site use any JS framework like jQuery? Anyway this might get you started in implementing option a above:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
        /*<![CDATA[*/ 
            .hidden
            {
                display:none;
            }
        /*]]>*/
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        // <![CDATA[
        function hasClass(ele,cls) {
            return ele.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)'));
        }

        function addClass(ele,cls) {
            if (!this.hasClass(ele,cls)) ele.className += " "+cls;
        }

        function removeClass(ele,cls) {
            if (hasClass(ele,cls)) {
                var reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)'+cls+'(\\s|$)');
                ele.className=ele.className.replace(reg,' ');
            }
        }

        function showComment(id){
            var hideID=document.getElementById('c0');
            var i=0;
            while (hideID!=null)
            {
                addClass(hideID,'hidden');
                i++;
                hideID=document.getElementById('c'+i);
            }

            removeClass(document.getElementById(id),'hidden');
        }
        // ]]>
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a href="javascript:showComment('c0');">show 1</a> 
    <a href="javascript:showComment('c1');">show 2</a> 
    <a href="javascript:showComment('c2');">show 3</a>
    <div id="c0" class="hidden">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="98">txt1</textarea></div>
    <div id="c1" class="hidden">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="98">txt2</textarea></div>
    <div id="c2" class="hidden">
        <textarea rows="4" cols="98">txt3</textarea></div>
</body></html>
```

This does rely on the ids of the elemets we are showing/hiding to be `c0` through `cN` with `N` being the count of elements to show/hide minus one...

Comment: how are you C.O. thank you for this answer but there is one problem still I can't know how much posts will be on the page, as this page is dynamic page so here you know you have 3 text areas so you can mange your 3 text areas but here I can't know how many posts will be there.

Comment: this is the link that I have on the comments
<a href="index.php?learn_id=2&comments=ok&id=<?php echo $blog->id; ?>">Comment</a> on<?php echo $blog->ByName; ?> post

Comment: You don't have to know how many items there are. In what I wrote it could be 2 (id `c0` through `c1`) or it could be 100 (id `c0` through `c99`) it does not matter as long as they all have a unique id that matches the pattern you choose. That's why the while loop - it will iterate until the first id it finds that does not point to a comment in the DOM.

Comment: OK my friend this is understood so let me get you on my point in your Example you have this "<a href="javascript:showComment('c0');">show 1</a>" as the link that the user should click to have his comment area available and here I have this like "<a href="index.php?learn_id=2&comments=ok&id=<?php echo $blog->id; ?>">Comment</a> on<?php echo $blog->ByName; ?> post" now how can I increase "('C0')" and about the "div id='c1'" also how this can be done I try the code and it working perfectly as static content but how to make it dynamically.
sorry if I can't get you point.

Comment: The idea was not to use your php links (which lead to a new page being generated by the server) but to put out all the comment areas from the beginning. Just give them the ids needed when you put them out in PHP and use those ids and your JS function on your links.

Comment: C.O can you please show me an Example on this you have my code above and I posted the link that I used so please show me little Example on this please I try to do what you told me but very sorry to fail